# MySQL trigger for updating another table on updating value in current table

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, phpmyadmin, sql-update

I have two tables A and B in mysql database. Table A having `brnd_id`, `R_2000ml`. Table B having `diff`,`val`. I am writing a trigger to update table B when `R_2000ml` is updated. I am calculating the difference of `NEW.R_2000ml` and `OLD.R_2000ml` and going to store the result in `diff` column and passing a boolean value as 1 to get updated in `val` column of table B.

Below is my trigger code which is not working as the values are not getting updated in table B.

```
DELIMITER //
  DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `myTrigger`;
  CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `myTrigger` 
  AFTER UPDATE ON `A` 
  FOR EACH ROW 
    BEGIN 
      DECLARE brndid integer; 
      DECLARE stkdate date; 
      if NEW.`R_2000ml` <=> OLD.`R_2000ml` 
      THEN 
        if NEW.`R_2000ml` > OLD.`R_2000ml` 
        THEN 
          update B set diff= NEW.R_2000ml- OLD.R_2000ml,val=1; 
        END IF; 
      END IF; 
   END;//
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Your trigger should be updating *all* rows in `B` . . . is that your intention?

Comment: Table B contains only one row and will be using for another purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your if clause  you use  "<=>", This operator performs an equality comparison like the = operator, so you should use <> or !=:

```
if NEW.`R_2000ml` <> OLD.`R_2000ml`
```

or

```
if NEW.`R_2000ml` != OLD.`R_2000ml`
```